# linux + the best way to install ISO file ( parallel installation )

Tags: linux

I have PC with XP windows with two LAN connections
One LAN connected to network 10.xxx.xxx.xxx (my private network)
And the second LAN (admin network) is connected to the Cisco switch
On the other side I have DL350 machines – support PXE,  (40 DL350 machines) , all  machines without OS ,and they  are also connected to the same Cisco switch

My target is to install linux.ISO (linux.ISO=redhat 5.3) file on all 40 machines, while the linux.iso located on my PC (C:\MY_LINUX_ISO_FILE)
Please advice how to install the linux.iso file on all 40 machines I need details of the process

remark:

I have limitation - I have only one PC with XP, I can’t use/get any other Linux BOX machine for kick start .....!

Comment: This is a non trivial task. You should hire someone to set this up for you.

Answer (score 3):

Given your requirement to actually install RHEL, you will need to look at setting up Kickstart:

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html

So, set up a single RHEL box out of the 40 you have, set up PXE there (Google for "linux pxe server"), and then set up Kickstart being run through the PXE.

Comment: Sorry but from your answer difficult to understate what I need to do , if you mean that I nead another Linux machine for the kick start then I don’t have!
I have only one PC with XP and 40 machines! , I not have other extra linux machines!

Comment: You will need one of your machines to run Linux first, and have it configured to be the PXE server which will give the other 39 machines the Kickstart bootup configuration.  I don't think you will be able to run Kickstart from a Windows machine, or, rather, it's not worth the effort in setting that up.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're willing to walk to each of those 40 machines to hit prompts, enter basic info, etc., you can set up the Windows machine as the PXE server offering the RHEL ISO. This is equivalent to booting each of the 40 machines and manually installing Linux. This is better than using CDs, but you will still be walking around repeatedly to every machine to answer initial setup questions.